# Solr queries not working on solr-7.2.1-0

Tags: solr

My queries that work on solr6.1 don't work on solr7.2.

I have solr installed on one machine running solr version solr-6.1.0-2. I have it on another machine running solr-7.2.1-0. I push the same documents to both instances. If run wildcard query *:* it works on both. But if I put in any q parameter on the solr-7.2.1-0 it doesn't work. But works as expected on solr-6.1. Facet queries work on 6.1 but not on 7.2. I am using schemaless and I have tried searching on _s, _i fields that are defined. solr's web interface schema tab shows the schemas as the same.

Comment: This _really_ sounds like differing field types. What kind of queries are matching (and what values are they matching) on the first instance but not on the second? Have you looked at the output under 'analysis' in the admin panel to see how they're being processed differently?

Comment: @MatsLindh both are string types. The Analysis Screen both has them using DA DefaultAnalyser only. On the search tab *:* returns all documents on both engines. Since I saw that string types are not tokenized but text types are, I tried to query where I used the entire field value, this works on the 6.1 box but not the 7.2. The only difference I can identify when looking at the schema is the 7.2 box says Unique Key Field
id
Global Similarity:
SchemaSimilarity. Default: BM25(k1=1.2,b=0.75) but the 6.1 box only has Unique Key Field id

Comment: must be something in here that makes it behave differently https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_0/major-changes-in-solr-7.html